# storing jpeg in spatialite database

Tags: raster, spatialite

How to store jpeg file in spatialite blob column so that spatialite gui and Qgis can recognise the format and show the image.
I have created in memory jpeg from raster bands using jpeglib and stored that in spatialite but spatialite gui can not recognise the format.
I also tried converting the whole jpeg to hexwkb format no results.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried rasterlite? I assume you want to display jpg as a raster layer?

Answer (score 1):

QGIS can't, as far as I'm aware, open images stored in blob format in Spatialite.